# JNI - Pass jclass as jobject to jobjectArray

Tags: java-native-interface

I have native method that returns Class<?>[] value. I trying to put jclass as jobject element to object array. But when i calling my native method from java, happens nothing (seriously, just nothing, method wont finish executing). There my code:

```
... other code where i makes some magic with classes
jobjectArray out = env->NewObjectArray(count /* count is classes count that i want to return */, caller /* method caller */, NULL);
for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    jclass clazz = classes[i];
    env->SetObjectArrayElement(out, i, clazz);
}
return out;
```

Comment: What is `caller` in this situation? The JNI spec it says `SetObjectArrayElement`must be called with the class of items, so `java.lang.Class` in your case. Also, please add error checking to your various JNI calls

Comment: I meant `NewObjectArray` instead of `SetObjectArrayElementmust` above.